# bootstrap inline-append not working on the search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I am trying to use bootstrap to append the button inside of the search bar, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsuor.jpg but it doesn't seem like it's working. It is being displayed on educomer.herokuapp.com, my code that I am using is

```
        %form.form-search
        .input-append
            %input.span3.search-query{:placeholder => "Search Food", :type => "text"}
            %button.btn{:type => "submit"}
                %span.icon-search
```

I have tried creating an entirely fresh app just to see if there was a problem with my code, but that wasn't the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Bootstrap are you using? I added the following to [your Heroku site](https://educomer.herokuapp.com/):

```
<div class="input-prepend">
  <span class="add-on">@</span><input class="span2" id="prependedInput" size="16" type="text" placeholder="Username">
</div>
<div class="input-append">
  <input class="span2" id="appendedInput" size="16" type="text"><span class="add-on">.00</span>
</div>
```

And it displayed as expected. Bootstrap’s [changelog](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/wiki/Changelog) says “support for buttons in input-prepend/append component” was added in version 2.0.2.

Comment: I am using 2.1.0, is it because I'm writing this code in haml? It seems to work as well when I write it in erb, is there a work around?

Comment: It’s strange to me that it works for you in ERb because it doesn’t work for me when I paste the markup you linked to on imgur.com. It shouldn’t make a difference that you’re using HAML unless there’s extraneous whitespace interfering.

Comment: Ah, yes, looks like whitespace is the problem. When I changed the markup from the Bootstrap example site to be all one line, the button moved to be alongside the field. Try adding the > and < symbols as described [here](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_).